# In Django does .get() have better performance than .first()?

Tags: django, django-models

The Django implementation of `.first()` seems to get all items into a list and then return the first one.

Is `.get()` more performant ?   Surely the database can just return one item, the implementation of `.first()` seems suboptimal,

Comment: It does not do that.

Comment: Thanks, I mis-understand the django code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason to think so, although I have not actually profiled.

Slicing on Django querysets is implemented by modifying the query to use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` terms to retrieve only the necessary number of elements. This means the `first()` implementation only fetches a single element from the database.